# STM32 LL SPI TransmitReceive DMA - interrupt not firing

Tags: stm32, spi, bare-metal

I was following this question / tutorial [STM32 SPI LL DMA Transmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558087/stm32-spi-ll-dma-transmit) to implement my own version of SPI TransmitReceive using DMA.

My code works well so far, it is transmitting / receiving on SPI, based on the Low Level drivers.

What's not working: I wanted to have an interrupt, when the transmission is complete, but whatever I have tried so far: the interrupt is simply not firing.

SPI is initialized once with:

```
// Note: called only once because the address of the peripheral does never change
// Configure RX
// LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(DMA, DMA Channel, Source Addr, Dest Addr, Direction)
LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(
    DMA1,
    LL_DMA_CHANNEL_2,
    LL_SPI_DMA_GetRegAddr(SPI1),
    (uint32_t)RXdata,
    LL_DMA_GetDataTransferDirection(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_2));

// Configure Tx
LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(
    DMA1,
    LL_DMA_CHANNEL_3,
    (uint32_t)TXdata,
    LL_SPI_DMA_GetRegAddr(SPI1),
    LL_DMA_GetDataTransferDirection(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_3));
```

The transmission is repeatedly started by this code:

```
// set RX
LL_DMA_SetMemoryAddress(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_2, (uint32_t)pRXdata);
LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_2, BufSz);
LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_RX(SPI1);
LL_DMA_EnableChannel(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_2);
LL_DMA_EnableIT_TC(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_2);
LL_DMA_EnableIT_TE(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_2);

// set TX
LL_DMA_SetMemoryAddress(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_3, (uint32_t)pTXdata);
LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_3, BufSz);
LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_TX(SPI1);
LL_DMA_EnableChannel(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_3);

// Start SPI
LL_SPI_Enable(SPI1);
```

the interrupts (Transfer Complete and Transfer Error) are "tied" to the RX DMA Channel - as HAL does.

The Interrupt is enabled in the (autogenerated) dma.c file:

```
void MX_DMA_Init(void) {

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel2_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn, NVIC_EncodePriority(NVIC_GetPriorityGrouping(),4, 0));
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn);
  /* DMA1_Channel3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn, NVIC_EncodePriority(NVIC_GetPriorityGrouping(),5, 0));
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);
}
```

The Interrupts for DMA Channel 2 and 3 are enabled in CubeMX and I can find the functions in the Interrupt Vector table. Interrupts in gerneral are active, because I can see the SysTic Interrupt firing. I also have a Timer, that triggers the SPI transfer with its interrupt.

void DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler(void) and void DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler(void) are existing in "stm32XXyyzzz_it.c". I added a counter variable to the DMA Channel 2 ISR for debugging, this variable remains 0 => the ISR is never called.

The Question: what do I need to do, to get the DMA (Channel 2) Transfer Complete Interrupt working?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: the issue was not the setup of the DMA, instead I was simply disabling the DMA to early in my programm flow. The DMA never reached the end of the transmission, therefore it did not fire the "Transfer Complete" IRQ.

The Code above is valid and working. I hope it will help others to implement their own SPI functionality with the Low Level drivers.